# Check to see if a year is a century

Tags: javascript

Working on some conditional formatting in d3 and need to check if a date is the turn of a  century or not. eg  1945 and 1998 are not, 1900 and 2000 are. Not sure how to go about it, perhaps checking to see if getting the full year and dividing by a 100 is an integer, but that seems a little non specific to me. Any help appreciated.

interval is the string passed to the function that denotes if the tick are ever month, year decade etc. I'd like to check if a date is a decade at the if (fulYear) condition, so its if fullYear or date is a century

```
function tickFormat(interval) {
        return {
            "decade":d3.timeFormat("%y"),
            "lustrum":d3.timeFormat("%y"),
            "years":function(d) {
                if (fullYear) {
                    format=d3.timeFormat("%Y")
                    return format(d)
                }
                else {
                    format=d3.timeFormat("%y");
                    return format(d)
                }
            },
            "quarters":d3.timeFormat("%b"),
            "months":d3.timeFormat("%b"),
            "weeks":d3.timeFormat("%b"),
            "days":d3.timeFormat("%d"),
            "hours":d3.timeFormat("%I"+":00")
        }[interval]
    }
```

Comment: `if ( 1900 % 100 === 0)  { //do your job }`

Comment: Ivanka was quicker, to explain why: the modulus is a good way, it will spare you some troubles about js conversions to float for divisions and subsequent test for integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the reminder operator - `%`. This returns the **reminder** of the division, if it's 0 then it's a century.

`if ( 1900 % 100 === 0) { //do your job }`

This way you don't need to check whether `1900 / 100` is an integer.